I am having an issue with my controller not calling initialize.my table is not being populated with the items placed in. Any help would be appreciated
Here is the Code sample. I have a table that I manually populate but it does not show up in the table. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't get any errors, just an empty table. I have pourded over this with my limited knowledge of JavaFX and scene builder.
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class MainSceneController {  

    @FXML private TableView<author> tableview;
    @FXML private TableColumn<author, String> firstNameColum;
    @FXML private TableColumn<author, String> lasttNameColum;
    @FXML private TableColumn<author, String> titleNameColum;
    @FXML private TableColumn<author, String> copiesNumColum;   

    @FXML
    private Label lblTitle;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtBook;
    @FXML
    private Button btnExit;

    // Event Listener on Button[#btnExit].onAction
    @FXML
    public void btnExitClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        // TODO Autogenerated
        Stage mainWindow = (Stage) lblTitle.getScene().getWindow();
        String Title = txtBook.getText();
        mainWindow.setTitle(Title);     
    }

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        firstNameColum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<author, String>         ("fname"));
        lasttNameColum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<author, String> ("lname"));
        titleNameColum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<author, String>("title"));
        copiesNumColum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<author, String> ("numcopies"));
    
        tableview.setItems(getAuthor());        

    }

    public ObservableList<author> getAuthor(){
        ObservableList<author> authors = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        authors.add(new author("Stephen", "King", "The Stand", "4"));
        authors.add(new author("Stephen", "King", "Carrie", "2"));
        authors.add(new author("Stephen", "King", "Pet Sematary", "4"));
    
        return authors;
    
    }
}

`

Well, I solved some of this. The initialize was not being called because I didn't state implements Initializable. Once I did this, My table started populating. But I only get the title data. I am not sure where to go from here to get fname, lname and numcopies, but progress is progress.
